# What's the minimum requirement for the DataSource property of ASPX server side data-bound controls?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to trace back the minimum type requirement of a data source that can be assigned to the `DataSource` property of data-bound ASP.NET controls.

I remember that I did this many times earlier every time with a few months or years' gap in between. I think at one time, I traced back the `DataSource` to be an `IListSource`, but I could be wrong. Or may be I am confusing the situation with the `DataSource` property of WinForms data-bound controls.

Anyway, I am starting all over again. The `DataSource` property of the `System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataList` class, for instance, is declared as `object`.

I am also looking at DevExpress controls and DevExpress MVC Extensions, which really inherit from and then delegate the data binding to ASP.NET server side control classes. They also declare the `DataSource` property to be of type object since they delegate the binding to the ASP.NET control itself.

Even in the DevExpress Extension suite, the `DataSource` property of the `DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.ASPxDataWebControlBase` class is declared to be of type `object`.

So, what's the minimum requirement? `IEnumerable<T>` I'd think. Or may be even just `IEnumerable` (the non-generic one).

Is there some place in the documentation that talks about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this helps you or not, but using Reflector on the class you mentioned shows the object being set to the DataSource property needs to be IListSource and IEnumerable:

```
    set
    {
        if (((value != null) && !(value is IListSource)) && !(value is IEnumerable))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(SR.GetString("Invalid_DataSource_Type", new object[] { this.ID }));
        }
        this.dataSource = value;
        this.OnDataPropertyChanged();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, Jason. I'd figured that out yet again but forgot to come back to this post and post an answer. Thanks for posting the answer. It will help me if I forget again and also it will help anyone else who happens to ponder over this issue.

Comment: Nitpick: you say it needs to be IListSource AND IEnumerable however the condition for exception being thrown is (not null) AND (not IListSource) AND (not IEnumerable)... the complement of that condition would be the acceptance criteria, but the complement of that condition is (null OR IListSource OR IEnumerable)... so perhaps the correct statement is the property needs to be IListSource OR IEnumerable?

Answer (score -1):

Yes the DevExpress ASP.NET controls can be data bound to anything that supports IEnumerable.

Online help docs:

[WebForms DevExpress ASP.NET GridView](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument3719)

[MVC Data Binding](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument9149)

Hope that helps. If you have other questions, please feel free to contact the DevExpress support team: http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/CreateIssue.aspx?issuetype=Question

Comment: Thanks, Mehul. Can you point me to some documentation because DevExpress controls, I checked, delegate to ASP.NET Server controls, which also can bind to `DataTable` objects, which, as noted in the question, are NOT `IEnumerable`.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to contact the DevExpress support team? They can help you quicker than posting here.