# What's the model posted to a Create/Edit action when a DevExpress MVC GridView Extension is bound to a System.Data.DataTable object?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, devexpress

I am using a DevExpress `GridView` extension v12.2 in an ASP.NET MVC 4 project.

The `GridView`'s `DataSource` is set to a `System.Data.DataTable` object, which is obtained by running a custom SQL query on a SQL Server 2008 R2 database.

The reason I am binding to a `DataTable` is that the results from running the SQL query will have a variable number of columns each time, so the schema of the results will be fluid. Hence, I cannot bind to a specific ViewModel or an `IEnumerable<MyPOCO>` because for that I'll have to have a fixed structure before hand.

I looked up and the `DataTable` is, surprisingly, not an `IEnumerable`. It is an `IListSource`. But [I digress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18631385/whats-the-minimum-requirement-for-the-datasource-property-of-aspx-server-side-d).

I am using the following code to handle row edits, deletes and new row creation:

```
@Html.DevExpress().GridView(settings =>
    {
    settings.Name = "gvStrings";

    settings.CallbackRouteValues = new { Controller = "Strings", Action = "StringsPartial" };

    // Paging related stuff: not shown here 
    // because it's not relevant to the question

    foreach (DataColumn column in Model.Columns)
    {
        if ((string.Compare(column.ColumnName, "Foo", true) == 0) ||
            (string.Compare(column.ColumnName, "Bar", true) == 0))
        {
            continue;
        }
        else if (string.Compare(column.ColumnName, "GarId", true) == 0)
        {
            var categoryColumn = settings.Columns.Add(column.ColumnName, "Gar");

            // and so on...
        }
        else
        {
            settings.Columns.Add(column.ColumnName);
        }
    }

    settings.KeyFieldName = "FooId";

    settings.SettingsEditing.AddNewRowRouteValues = new { Controller = "Foo", Action = "CreateNew" };
    settings.SettingsEditing.UpdateRowRouteValues = new { Controller = "Foo", Action = "Edit" };
    settings.SettingsEditing.DeleteRowRouteValues = new { Controller = "Foo", Action = "Delete" };

    settings.SettingsEditing.Mode = GridViewEditingMode.Inline;

    settings.SettingsBehavior.ConfirmDelete = true;

    settings.CommandColumn.Visible = true;
    settings.CommandColumn.NewButton.Visible = true;
    settings.CommandColumn.EditButton.Visible = true;
    settings.CommandColumn.UpdateButton.Visible = true;
    settings.CommandColumn.DeleteButton.Visible = true;

}).Bind(Model).GetHtml()
```

I am having trouble figuring out what type of object the data sent from the client is being bound to on the server.

I tried binding to a `System.Data.DataRow` like so, but the model binder fails to bind to a `DataRow` object because `DataRow` does not have a parameterless, default constructor.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateNew(DataRow row)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();

    // The model binder can't bind to System.Data.DataRow because
    // DataRow does not have a parameterless, default ctor, so 
    // I receive an exception that says something like, 
    // "No parameterless default constructor was found on this object."

    return Content("Hello, there!");
}
```

Then, I tried using `System.object` in the signature and calling its `GetType()` to return the run-time type but it returns `System.object` only as the run-time type. Please see the code below:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateNew(object row)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(row.GetType().ToString());

    return Content("Hello, there!");
}
```

Then, I tried binding to a `dynamic` object like so, and I am unable to reflect on its properties.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateNew(dynamic row)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();

    foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(row))
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(prop.Name);
    }

    return Content("Hello, there!");
}
```

Please help. What object should I bind the data to?

Comment: Why don't you contact DevExpress support directly?

Comment: Was pressed for time. Just in between things, I couldn't get to doing it. Posting here is so much more time-efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [GridView Editing values with DataTable Model](http://www.devexpress.com/scid=Q473431) thread in the DevExpress KB.

Comment: Thank you, Mikhail. I've looked up the sample code that Anthony posted as a response to Marcel's query in the link you pointed to and it looks like that's the way to go. Thanks much. I'm still having some problems, though before I get to the data binding on edit actions.

Comment: That's the gist of my most recent wrangle with DevExpress extensions for MVC. Can you help?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18871574/e-getlistsourcefieldvalue-returns-null-in-the-customunboundcolumndata-event-hand